# Eliminar header 'X-Powered-By' de respuesta Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de **eliminar el header *"X-Powered-By"* en una respuesta** de *Laravel 5.1*. Compruebo los headers en https://headerinspector.com/

Por lo que he visto no se puede hacer en el *.htaccess*, la mejor opción sería poner la **[directiva *expose_php* del fichero *php.ini*](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.expose-php)** en *off*:

```
expose_php = Off
```

El problema es que no tengo acceso a este fichero.
La opción en PHP sería usar:

```
header_remove('x-powered-by');
```

Esta fue mi segunda opción, que tampoco funciono. Esto fue lo que hice:
Crear un middleware, registrarlo y probar que cargaba (escribí en el log desde el método `handle()`). Seguidamente trate de *remover* el header en cuestión. A continuación el middleware con todas las opciones que probe:

```
<?php

namespace miapp\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class StripHeaders
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $request->server->remove('X-Powered-By');
        $request->server->remove('x-powered-by');
        $request->headers->remove('X-Powered-By');
        $request->headers->remove('x-powered-by');
        header_remove('X-Powered-By');
        header_remove('x-powered-by');

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

No funciona.

`'X-Powered-By'` (o su variante en minúsculas) no esta en el objeto `$request->headers` ni en `$request->server` (los trace con `Log::info($request->headers);` y `Log::info($request->server->all());`). Llamar a `header_remove()` tampoco ha causado efecto en este punto del código...

¿alguna idea?

Comment: Está en inglés, pero puede servir: https://danieldusek.com/enabling-security-headers-for-your-website-with-php-and-laravel.html

Comment: @Triby esta llamando a `header_remove('X-Powered-By');` y `header_remove('Server');`dentro del método: `removeUnwantedHeaders()` más elegante que lo mío, pero sigue sin funcionar para este caso concreto

Comment: La diferencia que encuentro comienza en esta línea `$response = $next($request);` y después se eliminan los headers usando `$response`

Comment: @Triby si te fijas **no elimina headers** en el punto en el que dices, esta añadiendo *headers* nuevos, esos los añado yo en el `.htaccess`, sería otra forma de hacerlo. La parte en que trata de borrar `'X-Powered-By'` que es lo que necesito, esta en la línea anterior a `$response = $next($request);`